# Round seconds of a datetime column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, rounding

I have date/time as one of the columns (output from a sensor). The seconds are recorded with decimals eg. 2022-05-10 10:30:15.6 . I want to round the seconds part of my datetime and have been getting errors. Using lubridate package it says: "Error in as.POSIXct.default(x, tz = tz) : do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXct” ". Any help is appreciated. Thanks for the help.
`structure(list(date = structure(c(1652178486.576, 1652178546.024,  1652178605.238, 1652178665.397, 1652178725.574, 1652178785.75,  1652178845.919, 1652178905.083, 1652178965.228, 1652179025.378 ), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA,  -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

Comment: Your `dput` is incomplete, missing the beginning. It should start with `structure(list(`. You also don't need to share much, 5 rows should be plenty to demonstrate a solution for this problem. And we need the beginning for it to work.

Comment: Define _"round the seconds part of my datetime"_, add expected output to your question as well as the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

tibble(datetime = c(
  1652458025.168,
  1652458085.343,
  1652458145.56,
  1652458205.746
)) |>
  mutate(
    datetime = as_datetime(datetime),
    datetime_rounded = round_date(datetime, unit = "second")
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   datetime            datetime_rounded   
#>   <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1 2022-05-13 16:07:05 2022-05-13 16:07:05
#> 2 2022-05-13 16:08:05 2022-05-13 16:08:05
#> 3 2022-05-13 16:09:05 2022-05-13 16:09:06
#> 4 2022-05-13 16:10:05 2022-05-13 16:10:06
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>